# Dative and Accusative Confusion

Tags: dative, accusative

I have some confusion regarding accusative and dative. Please understand my question or if I have questioned wrongly than correct me. And please answer the questions elaborately if possible. Thank you.

Q#1. In this German sentence why *Schüler* is dative, not accusative?

> Der Lehrer zeigt in dem Zimmer dem Schüler den Film.

Q#2. In this sentence why *Gesundheit* is dative?

> Das Rauchen schadet der Gesundheit.

Please answer the questions thank you.

Comment: What does your grammar book say about the Dativ and its use? Why would you expect the Dativ for "Schüler" in the first sentence?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "elaborate answers"? The short answer would be "because verb X goes with case(s) Y", so please explain what you think (or understood when checking your grammar or dictionary) and what exactly is your question. And only one question per post, please!

Comment: For the first sentence, I learnt that accusative has already used the word film. after that there will be one left word to use the dative. and if I question with whom then I found that Schuler is the answer. this is how I figured out the dative.

Comment: In the second sentence why Gesundheit took the dative? If I question with "what" I find the answer Gesundheit. So it could be dative or accusative now what? I am stuck here.

Comment: The is NO rule that there can be on only one accusative in the sentence so the logic "_there will be one left word to use the dative_" is just wrong.

Comment: stephie what do you mean by verb X goes with case? Is schaden a dative verb? thank you.

Comment: You have to look up the verbs *zeigen* and *schaden* to see what kind of object they take, you cannot deduce that.

Comment: You cannot ask with "what" in the second sentence. 1. "What" is not a German word. 2. You have to look in your dictionary the verb "schaden" and with which cases it is used.

Comment: ok . It means that schaden is used for dative. Then I have to learn which verb takes which case. It's so much difficult to remember every verb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ruler of each sentence is the verb (here: *zeigen* and *schaden*). Every verb needs some mandatory complements, and most verbs also accept some optional complements.

One complement, that every verbs needs, is the subject. (There are exceptions, but they are very rare.) All other complements are objects.

Every verb defines on its own which object it needs. Verbs with similar meanings (like verbs of movement for example: *gehen, schwimmen, fliegen, laufen*) very often needs the same classes of objects, but its still the verbs who define this classes

The verb *zeigen* (*to show*) needs three mandatory complements (same numbers identify same parts of speech):

> **Jemand<sup>*1*</sup> *zeigt* jemandem<sup>*2*</sup> etwas<sup>*3*</sup>**
>   (Somebody<sup>*1*</sup> *shows* something<sup>*3*</sup> to_somebody<sup>*2*</sup>)
>
> Der_Makler<sup>*1*</sup> *zeigt* dem_Kunden<sup>*2*</sup> das_Haus<sup>*3*</sup>

- jemand<sup>*1*</sup> (somebody<sup>*1*</sup>)
  This is the subject. **Who** is showing?
  Becasue it is the subject, it has to stand in nominative case
- jemandem<sup>*2*</sup> (to somebody<sup>*2*</sup>)
  This is another mandatory complement. It tells us **to whom** something is shown. In German this part of speech has to stand in dative case, because the verb *zeigen* needs the information *"to whom?"* in a dative object.
- etwas<sup>*3*</sup> (something<sup>*3*</sup>)
  **What** is shown? The verb *zeigen* needs this information *"what?"* in an accusative object.

The Verb *schaden* (*to harm*) is a little bit simpler, it needs only two mandatory complements:

> **Jemand<sup>*1*</sup> *schadet* jemandem<sup>*2*</sup>**
>   (Somebody<sup>*1*</sup> *harms* somebody<sup>*2*</sup>)
>
> Die_Säure<sup>*1*</sup> *schadet* dem_Haus<sup>*2*</sup>

- jemand<sup>*1*</sup> (somebody<sup>*1*</sup>)
  This is the subject. **Who** is harming?
  Becasue it is the subject, it has to stand in nominative case
- jemandem<sup>*2*</sup> (somebody<sup>*2*</sup>)
  This is another mandatory complement. It tells us **who** is harmed. In German this part of speech has to stand in dative case, because the verb *schaden* needs the information *"who is harmed?"* in a dative object.